# How do I remove an array from an array?

Tags: javascript

Here is my array:

```
var myarray = [["d1", "sections/Dashboard-summary.html", "Dashboard"], 
               ["add", null, ""],
               ["20", "sections/MW-1-summary.html", "MW-1"],
               ["21", "sections/SB-5-summary.html", "SB-5"]]
```

How do I remove the second element `["add", null, ""]` so that the new array is

```
[["d1", "sections/Dashboard-summary.html?781", "Dashboard"],
["20", "sections/MW-1-summary.html?903", "MW-1"],
["21", "sections/SB-5-summary.html?539", "SB-5"]]
```

That element might not always be in the second position but its first value will always be "add". How do I remove the array with the first value `(myarray[1][0])` of "add"?

Comment: Does this need to be an array?  For this kind of thing it would be better to use a linked list.  Otherwise you'll have to write code to iterate through your array, find the entry, create a new array 1 size smaller, and copy all the information minus the "add".

Comment: @Tyler: this is JavaScript. Arrays are lists.

Comment: @Matt Yeah you're right.  For some reason I completely forgot that fact.  Good point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> That element might not always be in the second position but its first value will always be "add". How do I remove the array with the first value `(myarray[1][0])` of "add"?

Use a loop with [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

```
for (var i = 0, myarrayLength = myarray.length; i < myarrayLength; i++) {
    if (myarray[i][0] === 'add') {
        myarray.splice(i, 1);
        break;
    }
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/YtLaH/).

Comment: slice will return the part of the array that you deleted and will not modify the original array. Splice will actually remove the element from the array.

Comment: After commented on your response I realized I made the same mistake :S

Comment: Note this from the question: "That element might not always be in the second position"

Answer (score 0):

Use `splice`, like so:

`myarray.splice(1, 1)`

See this [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp) for more information on `splice`.

Comment: [Please avoid w3schools](http://w3fools.com). [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide) is a much better source for JavaScript reference, in this case see [`Array.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

Comment: Splice works when you know the position of the element to be removed. But in my case the empty element wont always be in the second position. How do I find the empty element and remove it?

Comment: You could iterate over the loop and see if `typeof(myarray[i]) == "undefined"`.

Comment: @Matt Ball: Thanks for the link. I didn't know I was committing such an atrocity.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove it completely (slow):

```
myarray.splice(1, 1);
```

You can delete it from the array, and left a "hole" in it (left the position 1 undefined):

```
delete myarray[1];
```